# Doing T-test across two data sets to validate null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, spss

I have two features. I need to perform T-test for these two datasets but with the same model.

```
 train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = model_selection.train_test_split(X_pac, labels, test_size=0.2)

train_x1, test_x1, train_y1, test_y1 = model_selection.train_test_split(author_post_new, labels, test_size=0.2)
```

I need to perform T-test for the SVM model on these two datasets. How can I do that?

### Update:

I need to T-Test to check whether the Sentiment feature has a significant role in identifying gender from text. I have computed the TF-IDF feature and got `author_post_new`.
I have applied the Sentiment feature on the dataset and got `X_pac` from the dataset. Now I want to determine whether the Sentiment feature has a significant role in identifying gender.

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need to do a t test and why you're splitting the data?

Comment: I have updated my post. Can you please check ?

Comment: What do you mean by *validate* the null hypothesis? Are you trying to show that two means calculated from independent datasets are the same?

Comment: Please provide more details about the two data sets, how many cases, which and how many variables each data set contains, the modeling method you are using and the hypothesis you ultimately want to test. It's not completely clear that a _t_-test would be appropriate in this situation, at least as I infer from what's in the question so far. Providing more details would give you a better chance of getting a useful answer.